# How to to retrieve OSSEC's log alerts into Elasticsearch (ELK)?

Tags: elastic-stack, ossec

I have  tried [this tutorial](https://practicalassurance.com/blog/ossec-elk-stack-integration/). But it didn't catch the OSSEC log (alerts, syslog, etc), it just give me this message for my Kibana apps.

> Couldn't find any Elasticsearch data
>   You'll need to index some data into Elasticsearch before you can create an index pattern.

I know that there is some tutorial like [this](https://wazuh.com/elastic-stack). But it's required to use `wazuh` package and I dont want to use it, I just want to use the pure OSSEC. My OSSEC and ELK apps are located in the samw machine

My question is, How can I integrate OSSEC with ELK ? What configuration do i have to do first before starting connected OSSEC to ELK ?

Comment: what version of elk you installed?

Comment: @JosephMTsai 6.2.2

Comment: Does anyone know the answer ?

Comment: Hi, could you solve the issue as you asked? Or using wazuh?

Comment: Hi @MushfiqurRahman I could solve the issue using Hackslash answer, but i have to install the wazuh application, which is a fork project from OSSEC. Wazuh have capability more than original ossec do, so i prefer to using wazuh application, rather than use only "ossec". Wazuh also integrated with ELK.

Comment: Hi @Gagantous thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the data template so that Elastisearch can understand the format of the alert data. You can use the one made by Wazuh, or you could download it and modify it to "make your own". If you go down this road you will eventually end up trying to re-write Wazuh, which you don't need to do because it is open source. You can just download all the source files and do whatever you want with them.

**Command to load template:**

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wazuh/wazuh/3.2/extensions/elasticsearch/wazuh-elastic6-template-alerts.json | curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/wazuh' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-
```

**Download Template:**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wazuh/wazuh/3.2/extensions/elasticsearch/wazuh-elastic6-template-alerts.json

**-OR-**

You could just spin up a Docker container that is ready to go:

https://github.com/wazuh/docker-ossec-elk

Comment: is it required for wazuh app ? because it's from wazuh team, not ossec. Will it still work even it's from wazuh ?